# Using different versions of TeX Live on Windows

Tags: lyx, texlive, windows

I have a Windows 10 computer with LyX 2.2.3 and TeX Live 2016 installed.

I then installed TeX Live 2017.

LyX is still using TeX Live 2016, but I would like it to use TeX Live 2017, and perhaps even switch back.

Is there a simple way to have LyX use a particular version of TeX Live on Windows?

Comment: What's your PATH pointing to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to `Tools -> Preferences -> Paths` and change `C:\texlive\2016\bin\win32` into `C:\texlive\2017\bin\win32` in the `Prefix for PATH`.

I have the Italian version, I hope it's clear, anyway:

[image]

Of course, you can change that `Prefix for PATH` back to 2016, if you would like to use the previous version of TeX Live.

Comment: After I changed the path I had to go to Tools -> Tex Information and press the Rescan button and then it worked as desired. Tools -> Reconfigure did not implement the change in the path.