# How to specify the path to texlive in lyx?

Tags: lyx, texlive

At work I have a centOS computer, which runs an outdated version of texlive.
A texlive developer recomends installing the upstream version in [this CentOS forum](https://centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=60137). I installed the 2018 version of texlive. It has several path locations:

```
    <D> set directories:
   TEXDIR (the main TeX directory):
     !! default location: /usr/local/texlive/2018
     !! is not writable or not allowed, please select a different one!
   TEXMFLOCAL (directory for site-wide local files):
     /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local
   TEXMFSYSVAR (directory for variable and automatically generated data):
     /usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-var
   TEXMFSYSCONFIG (directory for local config):
     /usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-config
   TEXMFVAR (personal directory for variable and automatically generated data):
     ~/.texlive2018/texmf-var
   TEXMFCONFIG (personal directory for local config):
     ~/.texlive2018/texmf-config
   TEXMFHOME (directory for user-specific files):
     ~/texmf
```

Now I would like Lyx to point to the new texlive version.

[This question explains how to change the Tools / Preferences / Paths on windows](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/377218/using-different-versions-of-tex-live-on-windows). 
It did change Tools / Preferences / Paths / path prefix to `"/usr/local/texlive/2018/"`, but Lyx seems to be still using the old path configuration. 
See screenshot:[image]

I guess there is another way to tell Lyx which version of TexLive to use?

Comment: Maybe in the settings window (especially the *LaTeX Preamble*), or using *Evil Red Text*?

Comment: I have now switched to an Ubuntu computer which doesn't have the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If TeX Live is well installed, simply use the  <kbd>Rescan</kbd> button that you show in the image, then go to <kbd>Tools</kbd> > <kbd>Reconfigure</kbd>.

After some time a message will warn you about restart LyX. Do that and now it should work with the 2018 version.

BTW, yo do not need add `/usr/local/texlive/2018/` to any path in Preferences, but first, in a terminal, be sure that `echo $PATH` show `/usr/local/texlive/2018/bin/x86_64-linux`.